# Laravel loop through associative array then save to database

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I'm a beginner and currently learning Vue js and Laravel. So I'm trying to figure out how to create a single POST request via axios then insert multiple entries into my database.

I have this array for example:

```
{
  "comakers": [
    {
      "name": "Sample",
      "email": "sample@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "email": "test@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

then on my laravel controller I want to do a foreach loop like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    foreach ($data as $comaker){
        $nominate = new Nominate();
        $nominate->loan_application_id = $id;
        $nominate->comaker_name = $comaker->name;
        $nominate->comaker_email = $comaker->email;

        $nominate->save();
    }

}
```

But I get an error **"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"**. Can someone please give me some idea on how to achieve this?

And btw I'm trying to use the update function from my controller. Basically, I want to (insert new if not existing) or (edit when theres an existing data). Am I doing the right approach here?

**(UPDATE)**

laravel dd or dump shows this when I try to get the value of `$data = $request->all();`

```
array:1 [
  "comakers" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "name" => "Sample"
      "email" => "sample@email.com"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "name" => "Test"
      "email" => "test@email.com"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Error messages like that normally have a line number to give you a clue where to find the error. Can you show ALL the error message when you post here please

Comment: Hi Noah, can you update your question with the axios post, I think you're missing to find the array in the request

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data)` and show us the output please

Comment: @RiggsFollyI added the dump logs on question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `all()` will return an array of objects but instead an associative array. So you could try the following:

```
// Notice that you should use `json()` since the data is in json format
$data = $request->json()->all();

foreach ($data['comakers'] as $comaker) {
  $nominate = new Nominate();
  $nominate->loan_application_id = $id;
  $nominate->comaker_name = $comaker['name'];
  $nominate->comaker_email = $comaker['email'];

  $nominate->save();
}
```

of course you could also cast the result to an object like this:

```
foreach ($data['comakers'] as $item) {
  $comaker = (object) $item;
  $nominate = new Nominate($data);
  ...
```

I would also suggest that you simply print out the contents of the result in order to see what it actually contains, using `var_dump()` for instance:

```
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Hey Cyclonecode, I added the line `$comaker = (object) $comaker;` after the foreach and it actually solved the problem. Can you add it back so I can accept your answer? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Noah - Yes I added it again, but the only reason that is working is because the data is not an array of object as I stated at the top of my answer. The data is an associative array, so the first solution should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the `comaker` key when you try to loop, you should do it like this

```
$data = $request->all();

foreach ($data['comakers'] as $comaker){
    $nominate = new Nominate();
    $nominate->loan_application_id = $id;
    $nominate->comaker_name = $comaker['name'];
    $nominate->comaker_email = $comaker['email'];

    $nominate->save();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, since there are no objects but associative arrays in the result.

Comment: You are right, Laravel decodes json as associative array, I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your doing a foreach on the Json variable not the comakers object inside it.

```
foreach ($data->comakers as $comaker) {
        $nominate = new Nominate();
        $nominate->loan_application_id = $id;
        $nominate->comaker_name = $comaker->name;
        $nominate->comaker_email = $comaker->email;

        $nominate->save();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this shows another error "Trying to get property 'comakers' of non-object" instead

Comment: Right, I saw your vardump, you cant get the property of a non-object. Since its an Array, you should try `$data['comakers']` for the foreach and `$comaker['name']` inside the loop